# How to make an id field in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I want to make a field, which will be automatically filled, and stay unique.

More explanation: I have an ID field, which should be filled by my program not the user, and is my primary key.

How may I do it in SQL Server?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your ID column, set "identity" to yes and set the "seed" to 1.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Use an [Identity column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

```
create table MyTable (
    ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating your table simply set it as an Identity and that will give you an auto increment id value.  Example below.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    MyId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    MyColumn VARCHAR(500)
)
```

The `IDENTITY(1,1)` sets up the ID field to start at 1 and increment by one for each new record.

Answer (score 2):

Create an int field, and set its Identity property to Yes, or

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
[aaaa] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1):

Look to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(SQL.80).aspx (Identity fields)