# LINQ to SQL exception when attempting to insert a new entry in a database table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to insert a user in my database via LINK to SQL and I'm getting an exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into
> column 'UserID', table
> 'mydatabase.developer.Users'; column
> does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> The statement has been terminated.

I've marked the UserID as the primary key in my Users table and I was expecting that the SQL Server will automatically generate a PK when I try to insert a new user in the table.

I pretty much copied and pasted the example from [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://apress.com/book/view/1430228865) Chapter 4 Section on "Setting Up LINQ to SQL." Everything is in order... my database has a Users table with a UserID (PK) column and a Name column (both non-nullable), below is the class corresponding to the database table:

```
public class User
{
    [DisplayName("User ID")]
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    internal int UserID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [Column]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I also have a repository class which allows me to modify the database:

```
public class UsersRepository : IUsersRepository
{
    private DataContext database;
    private Table<User> usersTable;

    public UsersRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        database = new DataContext(connectionString);
        usersTable = database.GetTable<User>();
    }

    public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        usersTable.InsertOnSubmit(user);
        try
        {
            database.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var msg = e.Message;
        }
    }
    //...
}

IUsersRepository ur = new UsersRepository(connectionString);
ur.AddUser(new User{Name = "Joe"});
```

I've also tried setting the UserID to -1, 0 and 1, but I get the same exception!

```
ur.AddUser(new User{UserID = -1, Name = "Joe"});
ur.AddUser(new User{UserID = 0, Name = "Joe"});
ur.AddUser(new User{UserID = 1, Name = "Joe"});
```

Does anybody know what may be happening here? I'm really baffled by this: what could cause the SQL server not generating the primary key? Is there any way I can inspect the insert statement and verify what is actually being sent to the server?

Comment: Same happened to me on winforms. Did not find the solution and ended up using SQL strings with Context.ExecuteCommand(command1) which works all the time

Comment: @Mathieu I figured it out... auto-increment must be set to true. It seems quite obvious, but what's not so obvious is [what auto-increment is called in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718969/how-to-make-an-id-field-in-sql-server)... turns out it's called "identity" and setting the identity causes auto-increment so it works like a charm now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your primary key an integer? You need to set the identity specification:
[image]

If you are using something like a uniqueidentifier, you need to generate on the client with

```
User user = new User();

user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the properties of the table and make sure UserId allow nulls is set to false; make sure auto-increment is set to yes

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but I was looking for auto-increment and I couldn't find it. [Turns out auto-increment is called "identity"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718969/how-to-make-an-id-field-in-sql-server)